# Writing equations in the form of a conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

I'm presented with the following internal energy equation:
$$
\frac{\partial (\rho e)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho e \vec{v}) = -p\nabla \cdot \vec{v} + \nabla \cdot (K\nabla T) + \varepsilon_V + q_H
$$
and I'm being asked to say if it is possible to rewrite it in the form of a conservation law, and if yes, to identify fluxes and sources.

I am making the assumption that "conservation law form" means "in a conservative form". In that case, I would need to write something like:
$$
\frac{\partial (\rho e)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \vec{F} = Q
$$

Where the $\vec{F}$ term contains the fluxes and Q the sources. The $p\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$ is giving me trouble, as I can't easily rearrange it as the divergence of a vector. I tried writing that $\nabla \cdot p\vec{v} = p\nabla \cdot \vec{v} + \vec{v}\cdot\nabla p $ but that doesn't help.

Is the answer to the question "it can't be done"? And if so, what would you formally say is the reason for this? How would you describe the $p\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$ term?

Comment: It may help to note that $\nabla \cdot (fF)=\nabla f \cdot F + f \nabla \cdot F$. Rearranging, $f \nabla \cdot F = \nabla \cdot (fF)-\nabla f \cdot F$, and then you may hope that the last term cancels some other contribution, or is just zero by virtue of $f$ actually being constant.

Comment: (Another possibility is that $f$ isn't constant but its gradient is somehow always perpendicular to $F$.)

Comment: Thought about these possibilities but I don't think they apply. Might very well be that it's just not possible to write it in the form of a conservation law, I just don't know how to formally justify it